# "Filtering the paginated list" is not working on vue-paginate node

Tags: javascript, npm, vue.js, vuejs2

in my project i have added the pagination by vue-paginate node, and i added filtering by vue-pagination too and it works fine. When i type in my input field something that does not exist in my list it's blank and thats ok too, but when i start to delete letters nothing shows up on the list, and when i remove all letters the list does not appear, just the pagination appeares.

HTML:

```
<input class="form-control form-control-search m-input" autocomplete="off" type="text" v-model="search" placeholder="Search...">

<paginate class="m-list-timeline__items no-timeline" name="items" :list="fLangs" :per="10">
  <div class="m-list-timeline__item no-timeline" v-for="item in paginated('items')" v-bind:key="item.id">
    <span class="m-list-timeline__text">
      <span class="timeline-title"><span class="clr-black-light">{{ item.name }}</span></span>
      <span class="timeline-subtitle"><span class="clr-grey">{{ item.description }}</span></span>
    </span>
    <span class="m-list-timeline__time">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm m-btn m-btn--icon m-btn--icon-only m-btn--pill" @click="fetchAndUpdateItem(item.id)"><i class="la la-pencil"></i></button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm m-btn m-btn--icon m-btn--icon-only m-btn--pill" @click="fetchAndRemoveItem(item.id)"><i class="la la-trash"></i></button>
    </span>
  </div>
</paginate>
<paginate-links for="langs" :hide-single-page="true"></paginate-links>
```

Data:

```
data: function () {
    return {
      search: '',
      paginate: ['langs'],
      langs: ['Item One', 'Item Two', 'Item Three', 'Item Four', 'Item Five', 'Item Six', 'Item Seven', 'Item Eight', 'Item Nine', 'Item Ten', 'Item Eleven', 'Item Twelve', 'Item Thirteen']
  }
},
```

Computed:

```
computed: {
  fLangs () {
      const re = new RegExp(this.search, 'i')
      return this.langs.filter(item => item.match(re))
  }
}
```

Picture before search:

[image]

Picture after search and deleting letters:

[image]

Don't know why my list is now showing up when i delete the letters, or start deleting it. Can anyone help me please? Thanks.

Comment: Could you add `:key="fLangs` to the `paginate` component? i.e. `<paginate ... :list="fLangs" :key="fLangs">` I just want to see if you can force it to rerender when given a new list. That's not a good solution, but it might help to isolate where it's breaking down.

Comment: It is working but im getting this error too "Avoid using non-primitive value as key, use string/number value instead". Do you know what that means?

Comment: The problem with using a data structure as a key is that technically `const arr = []` is the same object after you mutate it, so `arr.push('a')` would not change the key - and therefore would not force the object to rerender. That said, it does tell us something about the situation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to our comment thread, we know that the `paginate` component isn't rerendering, for whatever reason. I'm not sure what would cause this, but what you can do is to set the `:key` to something that you know will change with the search value - the easiest thing being to set it to `this.search`, which, conveniently, is also a primitive.

So you *can* force the `paginate` component to rerender by setting the `:key` like so:

```
<paginate ... :list="fLangs" :key="search">
```

However, a better solution would probably involve debugging why the component isn't rerendering - perhaps it's a bug with `vue-paginate`, perhaps you're not using the component as it's intended (though this seems unlikely since the docs themselves use much the same code). Either way, setting the key on the `paginate` component should at least get you over this hurdle for now.

Comment: Sorry for asking again, when i click on my second page to show the list, the filter is not working, do you know why?

Comment: Sorry, no idea! Sounds like a problem I'd have to have more access to in order to debug. I'm not sure what "clicking on my second page" means, and I have a non-existent grasp of the internals of `vue-paginate`. I'd recommend looking into your implementation and `vue-paginate`'s documentation to see if you're doing anything wrong, and then its source code to see if there's a bug.

Comment: I mean the second page of pagination, or some other page, the pagination only works on the first page of pagination with :key="search", and without the :key it's working but when i type in something that does not exist in my list then its not working.

Comment: Thank you @BrianKung

Comment: @Reo93 I have the same issue with :key. Search works fine on the first page but on the second page, it doesn't show any results. Even though the pagination count is showing correct results for filtered items like "Viewing 1-3 of 14 results" but not showing the items when searching from other than first page. Did you found any solution? Thanks