# Vue + Vue-Paginate: Array will not refresh once empty

Tags: vue.js, pagination

I am using [vue-paginate](https://github.com/TahaSh/vue-paginate) in my app and I've noticed that once my array is empty, refreshing its value to an array with contents does not display.

```
<paginate
  name="recipes"
  :list="recipes"
  :per="16"
  class="p-0"
>
    <transition-group name="zoom">
        <div v-for="recipe in paginated('recipes')" :key="recipe.id">

            <recipe class=""  
                :recipe="recipe" 
                :ref="recipe.id" 
            ></recipe>

        </div>
    </transition-group>
</paginate>
```

This is how things get displayed, and my `recipe` array changes depending on a search.  If I type in `"b"` into my search, results for banana, and bbq would show.  If I typed `"ba"` the result for bbq is removed, and once I backspace the search to `"b"` it would re-appear as expected.

If I type `"bx"` every result is removed and when I backspace the search to `"b"`, **no results re-appear**.

Any idea why this might happen?

**UPDATE**

When I inspect the component in chrome I see:

```
currentPage:-1
pageItemsCount:"-15-0 of 222"
```

Even though the `list` prop is:

```
list:Array[222]
```

Comment: please show your JS code as well. Especially where you updated the value of `recipes`

Comment: It's a bug of vue-paginate https://github.com/TahaSh/vue-paginate/pull/95

Answer (score 2):

Paginate needs a key in order to know when to re-render after the collection it's looking at reaches a length of zero. If you add a key to the paginate element, things should function as expected.

```
<paginate
  name="recipes"
  :list="recipes"
  :per="16"
  class="p-0"
  :key="recipes ? recipes.length : 0" // You need some key that will update when the filtered result updates
>
```

See ["Filtering the paginated list" is not working on vue-paginate node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49692660/filtering-the-paginated-list-is-not-working-on-vue-paginate-node) for a slightly more in depth answer.

Answer (score 1):

I found a hacky workaround that fixed it for my app.  First, I added a `ref` to my `<paginate></paginate>` component `ref="paginator"`.  Then I created a computed property:

```
emptyArray () {
    return store.state.recipes.length == 0
}
```

then I created a watcher that looks for a change from length == 0 to length != 0:

```
watch: {
  emptyArray: function(newVal, oldVal) {
    if ( newVal === false && oldVal === true ) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        if (this.$refs.paginator) {
          this.$refs.paginator.goToPage(page)
        }
      }, 100)
    }
  }
}
```

The timeout was necessary otherwise the component thought there was no page 1.

Answer (score 1):

Using :key in the  element has certain bugs. It will not work properly if you have multiple search on the table. In that case input will lose focus by typing single character. Here is the better alternative:

```
computed:{
    searchFilter() {
      if(this.search){
         //Your Search condition
     }
    }
  },

watch:{
  searchFilter(newVal,oldVal){
    if ( newVal.length !==0 && oldVal.length ===0 ) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        if (this.$refs.paginator) {
          this.$refs.paginator[0].goToPage(1)
        }
      }, 50)
    }
  }
},
```